# How to switch to a new function in index.js

Tags: javascript

I basically have a router.post() function in my index.js, and I want to, inside that function, call another router.post() function. Like this:

```
router.post('/checkregisfields', function(req, res, next) {
var x = req.body.email;
var p = req.body.password;
var p1 = req.body.passwordagain;
console.log(x);
var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    res.render('index', {title: 'nDoto', err2: 'Invalid Email Address!'});
    return false;
}
if (p1!=p){
    res.render('index', {title: 'nDoto', err2: 'Passwords do not match!'});
}

// If email and password are all okay, "redirect" to my other
// router.post('/regsubmit', function(req, res, next) function
// What is the syntax/command to "redirect" to another post function?

})



router.post('/regsubmit', function(req, res, next) {
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just factor the common code into a function that can be called from two places:

```
function regsubmit(req, res, next) {
   // code here
}

router.post('/regsubmit', regsubmit);
```

Then, you can call `regsubmit(req, res, next)` from your other route handler too.

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you :)